# Trunk8 jquery plug-in only truncates until first breaking space. How do I truncate a whole post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, truncate

I'm using the trunk8 jquery plug-in with rails (http://jrvis.com/trunk8/#toggle) and it only truncates the first few sentences until the first breaking space. Here's my code:

```
<%= simple_format(@post.summary, id:"t8-toggle") %>
```

How do I ensure that it truncates the whole post? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `lines` parameter to specify the number of lines of text to display before truncating. By default, trunk8 will only truncate one line of text. Here's an example: http://jrvis.com/trunk8/#lines

Combined with the toggle example, your JavaScript should look something like this:

```
$('#t8-toggle').trunk8({
  fill: '&hellip; <a id="read-more" href="#">read more</a>',
  lines: 6, //update this number as desired
});
```

The advantage of using trunk8 is that it maximizes the amount of visible text before truncating. By using the code in Brian Petro's answer, you would be truncating after a fixed number of characters, which may or may not be optimal.

Disclosure: I am the creator of the trunk8 plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the RoR version?

```
 <%= simple_format truncate(@post.summary, length: 140) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I woud like to toggle between showing the first few sentences and  showing the full post with more/less links in the toggle functionality of the plug-in.

Comment: 'def return' in your posts controller file. In your views/posts folder, make a return.js.erb file. Use js/erb to retrieve the @post.summary. Use jQuery to prepend the div containing your truncated text. If you are CACHING your site, this will be very efficient.

Comment: ^^^ Try to fill in the gaps. If you can't just post more questions.

Comment: Isn't there a way I can do this through coffeescript or the trunk8.js file?

Comment: Coffeescript is JS, just another syntax. Trunk8 is loading excess libraries. But essentially your answer is yes, but, there are many other ways to do it as well. Above is how I would do it for a scaling application. In the end, it's about what you did, not how you did it. So I encourage you to read through the docs of Trunc8 and share with the community, your findings.